# How to create DDL schema (Hive) out of JSON Schema

Tags: json, pyspark, hive, schema, ddl

I have JSON schema create with printSchema() function of pyspark and i want to create a hive DDL out of this JSON.

I did googling and i don't find a solution. Anyone have an idea ?

Thanks,

Lily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a **spark** `python` function with example that you can use to create DDL from `dataframe` schema for a **hive** table creation.  Please adjust accordingly.

```
def sparkDataFrameCreateTable(df, T = ''):
    cols = df.dtypes
    ddl = []
    ddl.append("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {} (".format(T))
    kv =  df.dtypes
    num = len(df.dtypes)
    count = 1
    for i in kv:
        print(count, num, i)
        if count == num:
            total = str(i[0]) + str(" ") + str(i[1])
        else:
            total = str(i[0]) + str(" ") + str(i[1]) + str(", ")
        ddl.append(total)
        count = count + 1
    ddl.append(") STORED AS PARQUET")
    schema_map = ''.join(ddl)
    print(schema_map)
    exec_sql = spark.sql(schema_map)
    return exec_sql

df = spark.range(10)
spark.sql("create database if not exists junk")
spark.sql("show databases").show()
sparkDataFrameCreateTable(df, "junk.test")
spark.sql("use junk")
spark.sql("show tables").show()

+------------+
|databaseName|
+------------+
|     default|
|        junk|
+------------+

1 1 ('id', 'bigint')
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS junk.test (id bigint) STORED AS PARQUET
+--------+---------+-----------+
|database|tableName|isTemporary|
+--------+---------+-----------+
|    junk|     test|      false|
+--------+---------+-----------+
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but how can i do this with a nested son (with struct and array columns) j file ?